# How to edit value in excel

Tags: excel

Is there any way to edit the value from 10081300008817750017026931499 to 100.813.0000881775.00170269.314.99?

I have tried the LEFT() MID() RIGHT() like in the column i read about but still won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do here, try the below formula (assuming original data in cell A1)
Also make sure original value in TEXT formtat, not number.

```
=MID(A1,1,3)&"."&MID(A1,4,3)&"."&MID(A1,7,10)&"."&MID(A1,17,8)&"."&MID(A1,25,3)&"."&MID(A1,28,2)
```